# How to check the contents of a drag and drop. So you can match them?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, connection, contains, matching

I am trying to make a key and a door. You have multiple doors and keys. but the keys only fit in certain doors. So in a way they are connected. the problem is I don't know how to check the content of a drop space. So if I drop the key on a certain door how do I check what key is in the door. The code underneath is not the way to do it this does not work. because right now everywhere I drop the key the doors will always turn green I know why that happens but I can't explain it in English. Can someone please help me with how to check the contents of a drag and drop system.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log(ev);
    dropvlakcontrolle();
}

function dropvlakcontrolle() {
    const door = document.getElementsByClassName("door1")[0];
    console.log(door.dataset.lock);
    const key = document.getElementsByClassName("key1")[0];

    if (key.dataset.lock == door.dataset.lock) {
        console.log("match");
        document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        console.log("no match");
    }
}
```